# How to display indoor floor plan of a building with google maps api V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm actually doing a custom map with google maps api V3. I display some markers with info window etc. However, when i load a map with google maps api v3, i can't change the floor like that : https://www.google.fr/maps/place/University+of+Central+Florida/@28.6004069,-81.2011448,20z/data=!3m1!5s0x88e7685c311ead7b:0x6c3d25de16662ec5!4m2!3m1!1s0x88e7685c3221d257:0x42b6512e9a5cfe03

With google maps api, when i click on the building, nothing happens unlike with google maps there are buttons to switch the floors (like on the weblink in universty of central florida).

Does anyone know how to do that with google maps api v3  ? Is it a layer to add ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that's one of the many features of google maps that aren't available in google maps API.

They want to give their product an edge over the mashups other people can build with the API.